# View log messages from C++ when on non UI thread

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have a combined Java/C++ app. When I want to diagnose issues I often print log messages from C++ with the `__android_log_print()` function. This works fine so long as the C++ was called from the main thread, but if called from another thread, I do not see the log data. The multithreaded nature of my app is crucial to its operation. Is there any way of viewing the logs, or perhaps even viewing diagnostic output via some different mechanism altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__android_log_print()` works amazingly well from any thread, be it main thread, Java worker thread, JNI attached thread, or purely native. The `-v threadtime` logcat parameter is very useful. You should look for some other reason. Is the thread running at all?

Comment: Well this is embarrassing! I had put the logs in a location that was never executed! When it wasn't working, I had just assumed it was because it wasn't the UI thread. Its all working now.